# Why android:installLocation="internalOnly" is not working?

Tags: android

In my manifest file I have given `installLocation="internalOnly"` in the manifest tag and below in my upper part of manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.flexsin.classified"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
android:installLocation="internalOnly" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo_new_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
  >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I have send a mail with APK and when i clicked on Install button, it shows me, 
    " The  attachment could not be downloaded because the SD card is missing or not
    mounted".
    My question is why it is showing this message, when I want my apk to install on Phone
    memory.

```
Phone mem available space=50Mb
Phone model: Samsung GT-S5570
```

PS: device does not have SD card.

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem: What behaviour were you expecting, and what happened instead of that?

Comment: i was not expecting this " " The attachment could not be downloaded because the SD card is missing or not mounted"  because i told my apk to be installed on internal/phone memory.  It shud install the apk on device instead of showing that msz.  Is it clear now? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why it is showing this message

Because your SD card is missing or not mounted.

> when I want my apk to install on Phone memory

Your email client is trying to download your attachment. Your email client wants to download that attachment to an SD card. You can tell this because **this is precisely what the error message is telling you**. You would get the same message if you were trying to download a PDF file attachment, or a LOLcat image attachment, or any other kind of attachment.

> device does not have SD card

Then I suggest that you add one, or find some other way of installing your app (e.g., via USB cable and Eclipse or `ant`) that does not involve an email attachment.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying this  because my USB cable is not recognised by computer. :(

Comment: @GKT: Perhaps it is a cable set up only for charging the device. I have run into that with a few cables, though none that shipped with the device. Another option is for you to upload your APK file to a DropBox account, then install the app via the Android DropBox client.